# Why my latest commit not showing up, only the prev ones

Tags: git, github, commit

I'm totally new in Git. When i commit something trough GitGUI it's not showing up on GitHub only the previous one and I'm curious if I doing something wrong or it is meant to be that way.

Comment: Did you push it or only commit?

Comment: I've tried both

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're checking the following:

- You're looking at the same branch locally and remotely (Maybe you're pushing to different branches)
- There's something to commit (Did you make any changes? Did you `git add` those changes?)
- The commit command ran successfully (Did you forget to write a commit message?)
- The push command ran successfully (Does git know where to push your local branch?)

Make sure you pay attention to the messages on the screen, I'm not familiar with the GUI but if something happens it's most likely you'll get a notification somehow.